# What is the proper way to construct a clojure macro from lists of symbols?

Tags: macros, clojure

Imagine the following code to dynamically create a macro:

```
(def a (list '+ 1 2))
(def b (list '- 10 5))
(def c (list '/ 22 2))

(defmacro gg [h]
  (let [k# `~h]
     k#))
```

The intent is to pass a vector of symbols to a macro, do some evaluation on each element of the vector such that it returns a nice macro-esque form,  then have the macro combine them into a nice macro and evaluate it.  The above example works all except the actual evaluation.

When I run it I get:

```
(gg [a b c])
=> [(+ 1 2) (- 10 5) (/ 22 2)]
```

What is the secret to passing a symbol that is a list of symbols and getting a macro to evaluate them?  I have tried lots of combinations of quoting and have yet to hit the right one.

The real purpose of this question is to build an [Archimedes Ogre](http://ogre.clojurewerkz.org/) query based on a definition of a path through the graph.  If someone has an example of that, I would be grateful.

EDIT:

```
(defmacro gg2 [h]
  `(do ~@(map identity h)))

(macroexpand '(gg2 [a b c]))
=> (do a b c)

(gg2 [a b c])
=> (/ 22 2)
```

I was hoping to get `11` rather than the form.

Comment: `(mapv eval [a b c]) ; [3 5 11]`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid eval, hence the attempt at using a macro.

Comment: By the way, your macros can be simplified to 

    (defmacro gg [h] h)

    (defmacro gg2 [h] `(do ~@h))

Comment: It is not clear (to me) what you are trying to do. Macros don't evaluate their arguments, so there is no need to pass them quoted forms. They do evaluate their results. In what way are trying to combine the forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a macro. Macros don't do what you're looking for here. What you are looking for is `eval`.

```
(def a '/)
(def b 22)
(def c 2)
(eval (list* [a b c]))
=> 11
```

Of course, you can write a macro which expands into `(eval (list* ...))` if you want. It could just as well be a function though.

This is a very common mistake when starting out with macros; trying to write a macro which depends on the *run-time* value of its arguments. Macros run at compile-time, and generally the values of the symbols which you pass to a macro are not yet available when the macro is expanded.

About the use of `eval`, some cautions are in order. No one said it better than Paul Graham:

> Generally it is not a good idea to call eval at runtime, for two reasons:
>
> It’s inefficient: eval is handed a raw list, and either has to compile it on the spot, or evaluate it in an interpreter. Either way is slower than compiling the code beforehand, and just calling it.
>
> It’s less powerful, because the expression is evaluated with no lexical context. Among other things, this means that you can’t refer to ordinary variables visible outside the expression being evaluated.
>
> Usually, calling eval explicitly is like buying something in an airport gift-shop. Having waited till the last moment, you have to pay high prices for a limited selection of second-rate goods.

Comment: I decided to try this other language feature known as the "function" to good effect.  Thanks for the explanation.